# Can questions on meta earn the It’s Always 5 O’Clock Somewhere hat?

Tags: support, winterbash, winterbash-2015

If one were to ask a question on meta when it's 17:01 on Friday somewhere in the world (say, [Bangkok](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/thailand/bangkok)), which is subsequently upvoted, would it be hatworthy?

Comment: You haven't got it though, have you? I upvoted the post. Did you post it exactly one mminute past the hour?

Comment: @Mari-LouA On the main website interface (not tablet, obviously) if you hover over the "asked x hours ago", you get a UTC timestamp. This was posted at 10:01:07 UTC.

Comment: Hmm, didn't get the hat...

Comment: Got it for http://english.stackexchange.com/q/297133/9001, thanks!

Comment: You look kinda naked without your balaclava hat, it really suited you :) I hope you took a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly, but the question must be on main and not meta.

For example:

[What's the origin of "lit"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/297133/9001)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this hat secret has been revealed and is on the Meta StackExchange [secret hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270789/winter-bash-2015-secret-hats) post, so

> Yes.

Comment: Hmm, didn't get the hat...